# java servlet: get image from url and display it

Tags: java, servlets

How would I go about grabbing an image from a URL, and then displaying it... much like a proxy would?

I figured that I would need to first get the image to a filestream and then output the file.  Here's the code:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // temporarily hard-code the image
        String imageUrlString = "http://i.imgur.com/3lQAD2E.jpg";

         // Read the image ...
        URL urlConn = new URL(imageUrlString);
        InputStream inputStream      = urlConn.openStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte [] buffer               = new byte[ 1024 ];

        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = inputStream.read(buffer))) {
           output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        inputStream.close();

        // Here's the content of the image...
        byte [] data = output.toByteArray();

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(data);     
    }
```

However, the return is just a broken image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [OutputStream from the response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()) instead of the Writer. Writers deal with character data. Also you may wish to [set the MIME type correctly](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)) for the response.